# Obtain errors of individual data points when using cross-validation (scikit-learn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am using cross-validation to evaluate my ML models but now I want to look into the distribution of the errors, i.e. I want to get the average error of specific data points whenever they are in the test set.

```
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score

X = #data points
y = #output

lm = linear_model.LinearRegression()

kfold = KFold(n_splits=10)

scores = cross_val_score(lm, X, y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=kfold)
rmse_scores = [np.sqrt(abs(s)) for s in scores]
print('Testing RMSE (lin reg): {:.3f}'.format(np.mean(rmse_scores)))
```

Is there an easy way to get the individual errors of each of the data points whenever they are in the test set (not training error) using cross-validation with scikit-learn?
Thank you!

Comment: You mean to find all the difference between `y-pred` and `y-true`?

Comment: Yes, the individual differences of y-pred (for test-case, not the fitting itself) and y-true.

Comment: `cross_val_predict`?

Comment: @ShihabShahriarKhan That's exactly what I was searching for. Thanks so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, this should be what you are looking for.

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=3)

error = []

for train_index, val_index in kf.split(X, y):
    Xtrain, X_val = X[train_index], X[val_index]
    ytrain, y_val = y[train_index], y[val_index]

    model.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)

    pred = model.predict(X_val)

    current_error = mean_squared_error(y_val, pred) # error per iteration

    error.append(current_error)

 print(np.mean(error)) # get mean error after CV
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Yes, this was pretty close to what I wanted! With a couple of tweaks, I managed to do it. However, the easier solution was pointed out by @ShihabShahriarKhan above, with the function `cross_val_predict`.